# What "gap" could have caused the Starliner instructions to be delayed?

Tags: communication, radio-communication, cst-100

The Starliner launch [didn't go as planned today](https://arstechnica.com/science/2019/12/something-went-wrong-with-the-starliner-spacecrafts-first-flight/)

> After being released by the rocket, Starliner was supposed to use its Orbital Maneuvering and Attitude Control engines to provide the thrust needed to reach a stable orbit and begin the process of catching up to the International Space Station. But that did not happen.

What intrigued me was this part

> When ground-based controllers realized the problem, they immediately sent a command to begin the orbital insertion burn, but due to a communications problem—which could have been a gap in coverage of NASA's Tracking and Data Relay Satellite System or some spacecraft error—those commands were not received right away by Starliner. So it continued to expend fuel to maintain a precise attitude.

What do they mean by a gap in coverage? Is there some part of orbit that cannot be reached by a satellite or a ground station?

Comment: There are gaps in TDRS coverage.  Let me see if I can find a picture.

Comment: [Well, there's a 10-minute gap over the Indian Ocean on the S-band.](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/97440main_TDRS_fs_9.18.pdf) I didn't keep up with this mission's details, so maybe it was that.

Comment: @bishop that's dated 2001, how well does it apply to 2019?

Comment: @uhoh I believe it is still accurate. The gap exists because TDTS-1 and TDRS-4 are retired. [See schematic.](https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/heo/scan/services/networks/tdrs_fleet)

Comment: I have been looking for a current graphic showing the coverage but haven't found a satisfactory one.

Comment: Those satellites can be and have been moved in longitude, so their positions in 2001 may not be their positions in 2019, and their inclination drifts as well. [Why do the geosynchronous TDRS satellites have this distribution of inclinations?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26269/12102) and also [Why does TDRS 1's inclination evolve so much differently than that of all the others starting in 1995?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37449/12102)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was briefly discussed in the Dec 21 press briefing.

It wasn’t a gap in the sense of “no radio waves here”.  Rather, since the craft was confused about what time it was and hence what attitude it should be maintaining, it was also using antennae that weren’t optimal for acquiring the signal. The signal acquisition was slowed down due the resulting low signal strength.

More detail wasn’t presented, and my knowledge of TDRS is quite old, but it seems likely that the craft might have had to e.g. drop back to other antennae, perhaps low gain ones, when it didn’t have enough signal to get through the complicated TDRS lock sequence ([see section 2.4 here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20180003065.pdf)).

Comment: The more I hear from my former co-workers, the more it sounds like this is right. Bad state vector, so bad vectors to satellite.